# remove stain from granite tile

Tags: tile, cleaning, stone, granite

I have a bathroom tiled with granite tile floor and walls.  the granite is sealed with xypex (seems to be still well sealed) and is a salt and pepper quartzite granite. (see pic)

[image: granite tile with stasin]

one of the tiles has a dark stain on the surface about 6 ft up and to the right of the toilet, exactly where you might put your hand if you were urinating into the toilet.  so I am assuming its mostly just natural oil from someone's hand, but there may be other gunk in there (ewwwwwww).  anyhow, I have removed lots of stains from granite and stone on horizontal applications (acetone and/or poultices) but this ones awkward.  poultices wont stay in place, acetone runs off before it has a chance to work.  tried brake cleaner and various degreasers, all to no avail.  I made some progress just standing there spraying and wiping acetone, over and over again, but its too inefficient. I also tried spraying acetone on a sponge (which it attacked) and taping it up under some plastic film (the acetone dissolved the tape glue) but it didn't work.  anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If standard cleaners are not working, it could possibly be a natural coloration of the stone.

Comment: If you get toilet paper wet enough and slap it on hard enough, it will stick to damn near anything.

Comment: I know the discoloration is not natural as I have used this granite many times and its homogenous to the point of almost looking artificial.  plus, I have made some progress with acetone.

Comment: toilet paper was my thought too, but the acetone offgasses so fast that it fell off pretty quickly.  mind you, maybe I could do it repeatedly.  its got to be better than standing there spraying like a window cleaner.  you may have reminded me its a better idea than I first thought.  thanks